# Multi-projects dependencies with Webpack + Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I manage several projects, some of which have dependencies from each other.

Each project is written with typescript and build with webpack.

For now this is my tree

- root

  - tsconfig.json
  - core

    - dist
    - webpack.config.js
    - tsconfig.json (extend root tsconfig)
    - src

      - js

        - core.ts
  - project1

    - dist
    - webpack.config.js
    - tsconfig.json (extend root tsconfig)
    - src

      - js

        - project1.ts (have dependencies from core.ts or core.d.ts)

core.ts

```
 export class Core {
     constructor() {

    }
 }
```

project1.ts

```
 import {Core} from "../../../core/src/js/core";


 class Project1 {
     constructor() {
        let test = new Core()
    }
 }
```

If I run `tsc` from `/project1` the build will work as expected. 
But if I use webpack with ts-loader, I will got an error

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ...`

my rule from : /project1/webpack.config.js

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    use: [{loader:  'ts-loader', options: {configFile: "tsconfig.json"}}],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
},
```

I tried to add an alias without success

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        Core : path.resolve(__dirname, "../core")

    }
},
```

So I guess webpack is unable to jump to root if it's lunched from a child folder ?

I try to have this tree because I would like that each project can include separately in the html

core.js and a custom project*.js

I could have 30 different projects, So I would like core.js loaded separately to keep the benefice of the browser cache.

And keep the benefice of types in each project just by using the types of Core or reuse a method from a core component.

I guess I could make a package with Core then import in each project, but I have a lot to do for update each project just for a small change. Also as it work with `tsc` Maybe it could with webpack as it use the tsconfig.json.

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this kind of problems writing [layer-pack](https://github.com/layer-pack/layer-pack)

This plugin allow you to "inherit" some core project, including webpack config.

It comes with helpers like es6 glob resolving etc :)

You will find different examples that do this [here](https://github.com/n8tz/layer-pack-samples)

I'm actively using it on big projects so it's pretty stable

Hope it will fit your needs :)